# Compact way to express XOR between properties in an interface?

Tags: typescript

Is there a more compact way to express XOR between properties in an interface than the code below:

```
interface IPositionedProps {
    zIndex?: number;
    sendToBack?: boolean;
    sendForward?: boolean;
}

interface IPositionedPropsWithSendToBack extends IPositionedProps {
    sendToBack?: boolean;
    sendToFront?: never;
    zIndex?: never;
}

interface IPositionedPropsWithSendToFront extends IPositionedProps {
    sendToBack?: never;
    sendToFront?: boolean;
    zIndex?: never;
}

interface IPositionedPropsWithZIndex extends IPositionedProps {
    sendToBack?: never;
    sendToFront?: never;
    zIndex?: number;
}

type PositionedProps =
    | IPositionedPropsWithSendToBack
    | IPositionedPropsWithSendToFront
    | IPositionedPropsWithZIndex;
```

Comment: So the idea is that in the union only one of the properties should be present ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: that is correct

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to create a type which is a union where each member of the union is a single property, and not allow any of the other properties of the type to be specified, this should do that :

```
type Id<T> = {} & { [P in keyof T]: T[P]}
type JustOneProp<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: Pick<T, P> & Record<Exclude<keyof T, P>, never>
}[keyof T];


interface IPositionedProps {
    zIndex?: number;
    sendToBack?: boolean;
    sendForward?: boolean;
}
type PositionedProps = Id<JustOneProp<IPositionedProps>>
```

`Id` is just used for cosmetic reasons (to flatten out the `Pick` and the `Record`) and can be removed.

The type `JustOneProp` takes each property of `T` and creates a type where only that property is picked (`Pick<T, P>`) while all other properties (`Exclude<keyof T, P>`) are `never`